# Iterate through all the rows in a table using python lxml xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, html-table, lxml

This is the source code of the html page I want to extract data from.

Webpage: http://gbgfotboll.se/information/?scr=table&ftid=51168 The table is at the bottom of the page

```
     <html>
               <table class="clCommonGrid" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3">Kommande matcher</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width:1%;">Tid</th>
                                <th style="width:69%;">Match</th>
                                <th style="width:30%;">Arena</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody class="clGrid">

                    <tr class="clTrOdd">
                        <td nowrap="nowrap" class="no-line-through">
                            <span class="matchTid"><span>2014-09-26<!-- br ok --> 19:30</span></span>



                        </td>
                        <td><a href="?scr=result&amp;fmid=2669197">Guldhedens IK - IF Warta</a></td>
                        <td><a href="?scr=venue&amp;faid=847">Guldheden Södra 1 Konstgräs</a> </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="clTrEven">
                        <td nowrap="nowrap" class="no-line-through">
                            <span class="matchTid"><span>2014-09-26<!-- br ok --> 13:00</span></span>



                        </td>
                        <td><a href="?scr=result&amp;fmid=2669176">Romelanda UF - IK Virgo</a></td>
                        <td><a href="?scr=venue&amp;faid=941">Romevi 1 Gräs</a> </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="clTrOdd">
                    <td nowrap="nowrap" class="no-line-through">
                        <span class="matchTid"><span>2014-09-27<!-- br ok --> 13:00</span></span>



                    </td>
                    <td><a href="?scr=result&amp;fmid=2669167">Kode IF - IK Kongahälla</a></td>
                    <td><a href="?scr=venue&amp;faid=912">Kode IP 1 Gräs</a> </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="clTrEven">
                    <td nowrap="nowrap" class="no-line-through">
                        <span class="matchTid"><span>2014-09-27<!-- br ok --> 14:00</span></span>



                    </td>
                    <td><a href="?scr=result&amp;fmid=2669147">Floda BoIF - Partille IF FK </a></td>
                    <td><a href="?scr=venue&amp;faid=218">Flodala IP 1</a> </td>
                </tr>


                        </tbody>
                </table>
        </html>
```

Right now i have this code that actually produces the result that i want..

```
import lxml.html
url = "http://gbgfotboll.se/information/?scr=table&ftid=51168"
html = lxml.html.parse(url)
for i in range(12):
    xpath1 = ".//*[@id='content-primary']/table[3]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]/span/span//text()" %(i+1)
    xpath2 = ".//*[@id='content-primary']/table[3]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[2]/a/text()" %(i+1)
    time = html.xpath(xpath1)[1]
    date = html.xpath(xpath1)[0]
    teamName = html.xpath(xpath2)[0]
    if date == '2014-09-27':
        print time, teamName
```

Gives the result:

13:00 Romelanda UF - IK Virgo

13:00 Kode IF - IK Kongahälla

14:00 Floda BoIF - Partille IF FK

Now to the question. I don't want to use  for loop with range because its not stable, the rows can change in that table and if it goes out of bounds it will crash. So my question is how can I iterate as I do here in a safe way. **Meaning it will iterate through all the rows that are available in the table. No more no less.**  Also if you have any other suggestion making the code better/faster please go ahead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code will iterate whatever the number of rows. The rows_xpath will directly filter on the target date. The xpaths are also created once, outside the for loop, so it should be faster.

```
import lxml.html
from lxml.etree import XPath
url = "http://gbgfotboll.se/information/?scr=table&ftid=51168"
date = '2014-09-27'

rows_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/table[3]/tbody/tr[td[1]/span/span//text()='%s']" % (date))
time_xpath = XPath("td[1]/span/span//text()[2]")
team_xpath = XPath("td[2]/a/text()")

html = lxml.html.parse(url)

for row in rows_xpath(html):
    time = time_xpath(row)[0].strip()
    team = team_xpath(row)[0]
    print time, team
```

Comment: I love you.... Thank you for this wonderful code. How does this work? Since I'm new to Stackoverlow do i answer my own question wight his code that you provided me or is it enough that you wrote this answer so it will be closed? Also what does the .strip() do here? Because i tried to ran it without it and got the same results
Thank you again!! @Georges Martin

Comment: :-) You should see a checkmark on the left of my answer. Just click on it if my answer suits you...

Comment: Ok thats great :), one quick question. The .strip() method here what does it do? cause i tried to run it without that and i got the same result? @Georges Martin

Comment: There was spaces before the time text. " 13:00".strip() will simply return "13:00".